# Тире в предложении "Книга показалась мне интересной — я ее не купил"

Tags: пунктуация, тире, бсп

Я только что узнал, что при пропуске противительного союза следует ставить тире.

Сразу же решил придумать для себя пример. "Книга показалась мне интересной - я ее не купил". То есть "Книга показалась мне интересной, но (однако) я её не купил".

Возможны ли такие предложения?

Comment: В данном предложении употребление тире ошибочно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простите, не могу сослаться на источники, но мне кажется, здесь все очевидно и без вмешательства высших сил. 
Дело в том, что союзы служат для конкретизации смысловых отношений между частями предложения. Когда определить эти отношения не составляет труда, можно заменить союзное предложение бессоюзным. Но это возможно не всегда. Например, в данном случае, если изъять союз "но", возникнет ощущение, что, поскольку союз опущен, выражение отношений несоответствия не является целью сообщения. Мы начинаем искать истинную цель, но поиски заходят в тупик, когда нам становится ясно, что непонятно, почему же книга не куплена, если она интересная. Противоречие исчезнет, если дать понять, что другой цели нет. Союз "но" с этой задачей справится.

Comment: Я противоречивый человек... Книга показалась мне интересной – я её не купил. Подошёл трамвай – я пошёл пешком. Предложили повышение – я уволился.
))))

Comment: Согласна с Niemand, это предложение имеет смысл, если оно включено в описание определенной ситуации. Вот похожий пример: Он шел не разбирая дороги; сучья поминутно задевали и царапали его, нога его поминутно вязла в болоте, — он ничего не замечал.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш пример вряд ли возможен, разве что как авторский знак.
Тире как авторский знак можно ставить почти всюду. ))

Comment: Приветствую Вас, немецкий Mr. Nobody! 

Прямо везде можно ставить?

Comment: Я написал "почти". Вот, например, Горький обожал тире. "Это звучит – гордо!" Кажется, не наврал в цитате. Но сначала надо стать Автором, а потом уже ставить авторские знаки. )))